# Python script runs in Spyder but crashes (closes without error message) when packaged as a Pyinstaller .exe

Tags: python, pandas, pyinstaller

I'm trying to package a Python script as an .exe file using Pyinstaller. The script successfully runs in Spyder, but the .exe file abruptly closes without an error message midway through execution. I've tracked down the line at which the .exe closes:

```
df2['WholesaleCostPerUnit'] = df2.RetailCost/(df2.QuantitySold/df2.Quantity)
```

df2 is a Pandas dataframe. This is the first time in the script that I divide one pandas series by another.

Update: The .exe runs fine when df2 consists of 9,999 identical rows. However, if I try to run it with 10,000 or more (identical) rows, it closes at the above line without error. With this information I can build a workaround, but I'm still curious to know why this is happening.

Here's my spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['cannabis_transaction_sample.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\projects_local\\python_executables\\cannabis_markup_sampling'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='cannabis_transaction_sample',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='cannabis_transaction_sample')
```

Comment: To retrieve the error message, you want to package your file with the windows console enabled, test, and disable it when your program works. In your `.spec` file, it's there: `exe = EXE(pyz, a.scripts, a.binaries, a.zipfiles, a.datas, ..., console=True)`.

Comment: @Guimote Many thanks for the comment! I currently have the console enabled. How can I retrieve the error message?

Comment: Hmm that console should display raised errors like any IDE. It *generally* works for me. Does the console not show you the full error traceback and points to the faulty  line when the program crashes?

Comment: @Guimoute Strangely, I don't see an error at all. The console abruptly closes without completing the script. Maybe "crashes" isn't the right word to describe what happens. I'll edit the post.

Comment: try running the exe from cmd maybe? that way any printing to stdout  / stderr doesn't get thrown out as soon as the process exits.

Comment: I have recently given up trying to package my little python scripts up for distribution all the way down to a single exe file. I just run into never-ending errors. I have found a lot of success just making everything run from a portable installation of winpython, and then packaging the whole folder up into an installer with [inno setup](https://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php). for example, an app I made to chart Covid data for ohio: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KG0hIUMOIxm9C8COu7_ddmetypUiYoZ8/view?usp=sharing